# How can I take this inline function and convert it to a method while retaining access to this?

Tags: javascript, this

I have a JavaScript class that has this kind of structure:

```js
class MyClass () {
    myMethod() {
        myCallback = (response) => {
            // Do a bunch of stuff by referencing and altering properties in this
        }
        apiFunction(this.CLASS_PROP, myCallback);
    }
}
```

`myMethod` is already pretty long, and the contents of `myCallback` make it even longer, so I tried converting it to this structure:

```js
class MyClass () {
    myMethod() {
        apiFunction(this.CLASS_PROP, this.myCallback);
    }
    myCallback = (response) => {
        // Do a bunch of stuff by referencing and altering properties in this
    }
}
```

Whereas the first version works fine, the second one loses its reference to the `MyClass` instance and instead `this` is pointing to, I think, the call is the API that actually called it. I'm not positive as to why, but my theory is that "lexical context" doesn't mean where the function is defined, but where it's called.

But my question is, is there a way to break that function out of being inside of `myMethod` into an instance method of `MyClass`?

Comment: The second one isn't valid syntax. Is the `const` in `const myMethod()` a typo? Assuming you remove the `const`, it looks like it should work correctly. myCallback, being an arrow function class field, can only ever have the instance of MyClass as `this`

Comment: @NicholasTower yes, it was a type. ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to write that, one of them being

```
class MyClass  {
    myMethod() {
        apiFunction(this.CLASS_PROP, r => this._myCallback(r));
    }

    _myCallback(response) {
        // Do a bunch of stuff by referencing and altering properties in this
    }
}
```

Note that in `apiFunction` there's an arrow function and `_myCallback` is an ordinary method (=not arrow). The other way around, like in your code, it won't work.

The underscore in `_myCallback` indicates a private method (a convention, not a special syntax).